# Using MySQL JDBC connector, when to disclose source code

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-2

**Part 1**

I would like to use MySQL JDBC connector (called connector) licensed under GNU GPL V2 to exchange data to and from a MySQL database in my project, as far as i can read, If i add the connector file directly to my project and i decide to sell a copy of this project/application to be run on external servers, i would need to disclose my source code if asked for it.

As far as i understand this is because the connector file becomes a part of the larger project/application, and because the connector is licensed under GNU GPL V2 the entire project/application would need to be licensed under the same or similar license?

**Part 2**

From a thread on stackoverflow i read a comment that said, that if the connector is part of a separate project and you use that project to communicate with the SQL server, only the source code for the project running the connector would need to be disclosed.

**Question**

If i use the connector as a datasource managed by the server, so my project would not directly contain the connector file. Would my project than still fall under the GNU GPL V2 license?